# Systemd unit does nothing

Tags: debian, mount, systemd

I need to mount a filesystem after another one but because there is apparently no way to specify an order in `/etc/fstab`, I made a systemd unit file like that:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/mount /mnt/dir

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is that it doesn't fail, but it doesn't succeed either. When I manually do `systemctl restart <service>` nothing happen, the filesystem is not mounted. If I do `mount /mnt/dir` it works though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dedicated mount unit :

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount Unit
After=another-mount.mount

[Mount]
What=/something
Where=/to/destination
Type=ext4
Options=defaults

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Adapt this to you need.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#fstab